# Trying to connect from iOS to MySQL Database using php ( HTTP POST )

Tags: php, sql, swift, http, post

Below is my sample code for my PHP program, and my database has already been created.

**createteam.php:**

```
<?php 
$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

//getting values
$teamName = $_POST['name'];
$memberCount = $_POST['member'];

//including the db operation file
require_once '../includes/DbOperation.php';

$db = new DbOperation();

//inserting values 
if($db->createTeam($teamName,$memberCount)){
    $response['error']=false;
    $response['message']='Team added successfully';
}else{

    $response['error']=true;
    $response['message']='Could not add team';
}

}else{
$response['error']=true;
$response['message']='You are not authorized';
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

**config.php:**

```
<?php

define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'iphone');
```

**DbConnect.php:**

```
<?php

class DbConnect
{
private $conn;

function __construct()
{
}

/**
 * Establishing database connection
 * @return database connection handler
 */
function connect()
{
    require_once 'Config.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    // Check for database connection error
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    // returing connection resource
    return $this->conn;
}
}
```

**DbOperation.php:**

```
 <?php

 class DbOperation
 {
 private $conn;


 function __construct()
 {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Config.php';
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
    // opening db connection
    $db = new DbConnect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}

//Function to create a new user
public function createTeam($name, $memberCount)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO team(name, member) values(?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $name, $memberCount);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    if ($result) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

 }
```

However when I use HTTP POST method using Postman in Chrome, it states this

> Notice: Undefined index: name in D:\xampp\htdocs\TestServ\api\createteam.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: member in D:\xampp\htdocs\TestServ\api\createteam.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'iphone' in D:\xampp\htdocs\TestServ\includes\DbConnect.php on line 20
>   Failed to connect to MySQL: Unknown database 'iphone'
>   Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in D:\xampp\htdocs\TestServ\includes\DbOperation.php on line 20
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on null in D:\xampp\htdocs\TestServ\includes\DbOperation.php:21 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\TestServ\api\createteam.php(18): DbOperation->createTeam(NULL, NULL) #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\TestServ\includes\DbOperation.php on line 21

What does this mean, and what should I change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index) Start with that question.

Answer (score 0):

Your first two errors are caused because of these two lines:

```
$teamName = $_POST['name'];
$memberCount = $_POST['member'];
```

The error (`Undefined index`) tells you that you have some non-existing variables, in this case `name` and `member` from your `$_POST[]` variable. Make sure your POST request is correctly made, see [undefined variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index) for more information.

Your third error (`Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1049)`) is caused because there isn't a database called `iphone` in your database system. Check if you have typed it correctly or if you haven't yet created an actual database with the name `iphone`.

The last error is caused because of the first two errors, since `name` and `member` aren't (correctly) defined in your POST request they have been set to `NULL` and the mysqli library doesn't like that.